# Create XML using Coldfusion and Pass XML to SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, xml, coldfusion

I'm trying to create XML using coldfusion and pass it to an SQL Stored Procedure.

Currently I have something like this:

```
<cfxml variable="objXml">
<imp>
<data>
  <date>3/20/2023</date>
  <name>John</name>
  <CC>US</CC>
</data>
</imp>
</cfxml>
```

`<cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_SQLXML" dbvarname="@xmlData" value="#objXml.toString()#" null="no">`

I've tried a bunch of different things. Changing the type from SQLXML to CLOB. Using ENCODEFORHTML(objXML), XMLPARSE(), etc.

I'm trying to troubleshoot some old code that was using:
`createObject("java", "java.lang.StringBuilder")`

The string builder seems more intuitive but it's failing so I'm trying to start as simple as possible and nothing I'm trying is working.

When I try to pass objXml, initially I get SQL stating it can't change the encode type.

So I tried this from the coldfusion reference page:

```
<cfset myvar=toString(xmlobject)>
<cfset mynewvar=replace(myvar, "UTF-8", "utf-16")>
```

That didn't help. I also tried to completely remove the 'xml version' node from the xml entirely but was unsuccessful.

The old method using string builder, appends xml nodes one by one, and passes the xml using .toString() and the CFSQLType is CLOB.

What is the best way to create XML using coldfusion?

Specifically, I am working with a comma delimited list and I'm turning that list into XML and sending it to a stored procedure.

I pretty much have the SQL side down when it comes to processing and storing the XML fields into tables, once it makes its way to the stored procedure, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I need to do to get it there.

Edit:
Here is the important SQL code:

```
DECLARE
@xmlData XML = ''

/*
When using ENCODEFORHTML():
@xmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <imp> <data> <date>3/20/2023</date> <name>John</name> <CC>US</CC></data></imp>'

When using .toString():
Stored procedure errors out and states 'unable to switch the encoding'.
*/

SELECT  
dataElements.ID.value('date[1]', 'Date') as DT,
dataElements.ID.value('name[1]', 'varchar(12)') as NA_TE,
dataElements.ID.value('CC[1]', 'char(2)') as CNY_CD
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/imp/data') as dataElements(ID);
```

I'm not really concerned about this part, I think the issue comes from trying to pass in the coldfusion variable. It might have something to do with the '<?xml version' section. I just get SQL errors when trying to pass in objXml.

That's why I'm asking how to create XML in coldfusion and pass it to the stored procedure. I think if I can just get confirmation on that, I'll be ok moving forward.

When I pass objXML using objXML.toString() I get this error:
'unable to switch the encoding'

I notice that when I print objXML.toString() on the front end, it is missing the xml nodes.

I can print the XML nodes using ENCODEFORHTML(), and I tried passing into the sproc like that and it actually seems to work better than using toString(), the sproc actually runs and returns a message. It doesn't work successfully still but it at least runs.

Using .toString() causes the sproc to not even execute, or so it seems.

objXML.toString() produces this on the front end:
3/20/2023 John US

Using ENCODEFORHTML(objXML) produces this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <imp> <data> <date>3/20/2023</date> <name>John</name> <CC>US</CC></data></imp>
```

Final Edit:
Thanks to the folks that tried to help. In the end I was not able to solve my issue but ended up realizing the old code was working so I went with that.

For whatever reason, SQL server was not cooperating with the XML I passed in from the cfstoredproc but it did work when I executed the query manually.

Not sure what the problem was but, after realizing the old code actually worked, I just went that route.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I can't pass my xml to the stored procedure. I'd like to know what the best way to create XML using coldfusion is and how to send it to a stored procedure.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add SQL Server side code too.

Comment: Also include the error message and the datatype for the field in question.

Comment: Please provide for the `DECLARE @xmlData XML = ''` actual XML on the SQL Server side.

Comment: I added question marks to the T-SQL portion of code. Please provide actual value for the XML on the SQL Server side.

Comment: SQL Server strips out XML prolog declaration: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. So, you can remove its generation in your coldfusion code.

Comment: Coldfusion automatically adds that, I'm not adding it in my coldfusion code. It is simply being output when I use ENCODEFORHTML(), which is the only way the sproc runs. Using .toString(), it fails.

Comment: You don't say what SQL engine you're using. Assuming it is MS SQL Server, can you successfully execute the stored procedure using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @EddieLotter I'm using SSMS or SQL Server/T-SQL I think are the right names. I was able to run the stored procedure manually using my xml variable but I had to remove the 'N'' prefix it placed on the XML variable. Whenever you try to execute procedure on SSMS it puts N' before the variable's value.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following on the SQL Server side.

I struggled to get your XML sample verbatim.

Notable points:

- `text()` is used in the XPath expressions for each XML element for performance
  reasons.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <imp>
        <data>
            <date>3/20/2023</date>
            <name>John</name>
            <CC>US</CC>
        </data>
    </imp>';

SELECT c.value('(date/text())[1]', 'DATE') as DT,
    c.value('(name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as NA_TE,
    c.value('(CC/text())[1]', 'CHAR(2)') as CNY_CD
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/imp/data') as t(c);
```

**Output**

| DT | NA_TE | CNY_CD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-20 | John | US |

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding... The xml doesn't litterally contain '<cfxml>'. <cfxml> creates a coldfusion xml object, it is front end code. The XML object that is output using ENCODEFORHTML(objXML) is this : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <imp> <data> <date>3/20/2023</date> <name>John</name> <CC>US</CC></data></imp>.

Comment: Using .toString() it appears as just the data without the xml: 3/20/2023 John US

Comment: My comment above says: *"Please provide for the DECLARE @xmlData XML = '' actual XML on the SQL Server side."*

Comment: The actual XML on the server side is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <imp> <data> <date>3/20/2023</date> <name>John</name> <CC>US</CC></data></imp> when I use ENCODEFORHTML() to pass it in, otherwise, the sproc errors out and I can't output anything.